# Finite continued fraction in latex

Tags: math-mode

I need an output as shown in the attached pic. Currently i have the following in latex

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\begin{document}
$$ a_0+\cfrac{b_1}{a_1 +\cfrac{b_2}{a_2 +\cfrac{b_3}
                    {a_3 + \ddots + \cfrac{b_n}{a_n}}}} $$
\end{document}
```

Please help![image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxOcI.jpg)

Comment: Please edit your question to provide a complete example people can compile. What about the end needs tweaking? Which end? I'm assuming this is not really engine-specific, so I've removed the `pdftex` and added `math-mode` instead. Please note the descriptions when adding tags as they explain how they should be used.

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps squeeze and `array` in the denominator?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\[ b_0+\cfrac{b_1}{a_1 +\cfrac{b_2}{a_2 +\cfrac{b_3}{
      \begin{array}{@{}c@{}c@{}c@{}}
        a_3 + {}\\ &\ddots\\ &&{}+ \cfrac{b_n}{a_n}
      \end{array}
    }}} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

The usual notation is this however:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\[ b_0+\cfrac{b_1}{a_1 +\cfrac{b_2}{a_2 +\cfrac{b_3}{\ddots + \cfrac{b_n}{a_n}}}} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to get a better end term "+\cfrac{b_n}{a_n}" alignment. I wouldn't prefer usual notation though. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here I define `\lastcfrac` for the dots and the last fraction:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\lastcfrac}[2]{%
  \vphantom{\cfrac{#1}{#2}}%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr1ex-\height}{%
    $\displaystyle
      \raisebox{.5\height}{$\ddots$}+\cfrac{#1}{#2}
    $%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\[
b_0+\cfrac{b_1}{a_1 +\cfrac{b_2}{a_2 +\cfrac{b_3}{a_3 + \lastcfrac{b_n}{a_n}}}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is more a comment on @HenriMenke's second solution (usual notation) than a stand alone answer. As a first attempt I would lower the last denominator slightly to get alignment better.

```
\[ 
  b_0+\cfrac{b_1}{a_1 +\cfrac{b_2}{a_2 +\cfrac{b_3}{\ddots \raisebox{-0.9em}{\ensuremath{+ \cfrac{b_n}{a_n}}}}}} 
\]
```

[image]

But then, to me the notation given in the question with `+ \cfrac{b_n}{a_n}` looks a bit strange. I would like to have the dots following the `a` terms instead of the `+`.

```
\[ 
  b_0+\cfrac{b_1}{a_1 +\cfrac{b_2}{a_2 +\cfrac{b_3}{\llap{\ensuremath{\ddots}} \raisebox{-0.8em}{\ensuremath{a_{n-1} + \cfrac{b_n}{a_n}}}}}} 
\]
```

[image]